# Problems with monitor

Tags: hp, display-resolution, monitor

Recently my fathers gave me a new PC (windows vista business HP), and I have some problems with the monitors. When I use a Nevir monitor (42", 1920x1080), everything seems to be right, but when I connect another HP monitor (HP L1950), the monitor says: out of signal, and it turns off in a black window(but the monitor keeps running). I read that I need to press F8 to change the monitor to RGB, but this doesn't seem to work. Can someone help? It's because of the drivers?
Thanks. 
(Edit: right now the PC is running Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are connecting another one more display to your pc. If that is like it, you go to 'System settings' --> 'Displays' select 'All Display' instead of 'Built-in Display' and click on 'Detect Display' and 'Apply' and click 'Keep this configuration'. try with this it may works...
All the Best...

Comment: thanks! I will try this, and return here to say how this worked!